# PSEXEC...DTEXEC ERROR 128

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, psexec

I'm using PSEXEC within batch files to execute DTEXEC (SQL SSIS jobs) as part of a scheduling system. What I'm finding is when a bunch of jobs are triggered together (or even close to one another) I get multiple ERROR 128 messages and the DTEXEC jobs immediately abort. I'm guessing there is some sort of problem running multiple instances of DTEXEC (or at least a maximum allowed number).

Aside from staggering the jobs is there any other settings or ways to avoid the errors?

Comment: Can you provide the full error message?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds similar to this error resolved here:

[SSIS Package Execution using dtexec utility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805424/ssis-package-execution-using-dtexec-utility)