# Transfer Data from Local MySQL server to remote SQL server?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I need to make a procedure or find a solution in order to copy, at the end of each day, data that was added to my `local MySQL` server over to a `Remote SQL server`.

I am likely going to code a small app in .net to simply pull the data from the `local MySQL server` and insert it into the `Remote SQL server`, and just run the app on a schedule.

However, If I can avoid doing this and move the data with a procedure or a job that would be preferable.

Any suggestions for a solution?

Comment: Use SSIS, it's included in SSMS and supports OLE-DB and ODBC databases and sources and destinations.

Comment: As @Dai suggested, you can use SSIS. The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846135/schedule-ssis-package-execution) explains how to setup a scheduled job.

Comment: Not exactly what you asked, but could replication be a solution? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-replication-primary-secondary-replication.html