# How to automate daily task using SQL Server Agent or anything?

Tags: python, sql, cmd

Please help me out, I need to find a way to download a daily transaction from a website and automate it to run every day. The website requires a login and then I need to apply two parameters just to get yesterday's data the last task is to press a download button and download it to a shared folder. Is there a way to do this using SSIS, Command Prompt, or SQL Server Agent?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try scheduling a job using SSIS? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846135/schedule-ssis-package-execution

Answer (score 0):

For pushing buttons and the like, I used [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).
It has support for most modern browsers, and you can run it headless so it does not interfere with normal operation. Here's a very rudimentary example of what logging in could be like:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import selenium as selenium
import time

count = time.time()

while 1:
    if time.time() >= count: # set whatever time constraints you like
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        driver.get('https://google.com')
        print("Going to webpage...")

        time.sleep(15) # wait for the page to load

        username = driver.find_element_by_id('login_username')
        username.send_keys('username')
        password = driver.find_element_by_id('login_password')
        password.send_keys('superpassword123')

        login = driver.find_element_by_name('login_submit')
        login.submit() # click the log in button
        print("Logging in...")
        # get stuff you want from the webpage
        count = time.time()+86400 # add 24hrs cooldown until next attempt
        driver.quit()
```

I ultimately abandoned using python for this, since even though it runs in the background just fine, it still ate quite a bit of my memory. Perhaps you could set something up with the [Windows Task Scheduler](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10) or your OS alternative?

EDIT: You tagged this as [python], so I assume you're fine with a python suggestion.