# Calling an SSIS package using a Web Application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql-server-2005, ssis

How do you call an SSIS package using a Web Application?  I'm using SQL Server 2005.  I prefer a solution in C#2.0 above.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at this StackOverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805424/ssis-package-execution-using-dtexec-utility).