# SQL Server : SSIS - Package Issue not inserting data

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I run my package in Visual Studio it successfully inserts all the records in table

but when I scheduled it as a JOB, it shows its running but doesn't insert any record in table.

Can anyone please advise

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like it is a security issue.  Under what context are you running the job?  What exactly does the job do?

Most likely your SQL Server Agent service account does not have the proper permissions to do what your SSIS package needs.  Grant the necessary rights and try again to start the job.

Edit: your job package seems like its a very different version. Can you give us some version numbers?

Comment: I found this article - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805424/ssis-package-execution-using-dtexec-utility

Comment: I found this article - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805424/ssis-package-execution-using-dtexec-utility and did everything mention in it by it still doesn't work - you are right its  SECURITY ISSUE

Comment: got this error finally - Description: The task "ETL Daily Load Failed" cannot run on this edition of Integration Services. It requires a higher level edition.

Comment: @ConradJagger I modified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to Check first if your JOB on sql server executes successful to test it :

   right click on your job > Start Job at Step....
2. Then view its history...i assumed that there will be an error there thats why its not inserting new record.
3. Check your Connectionstring on your source and destination table if its correct.
4. You can also add [Protection Level of your Packages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141747.aspx)

Regards